# How to add missing times in column in Excel for interpolation

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with data in two columns as Time and Temperature. The Time column has values such as follows, where there are some skipped seconds:

```
2017-10-17 14:18:15    
2017-10-17 14:18:17    
2017-10-17 14:18:18    
2017-10-17 14:18:19    
2017-10-17 14:18:21    
2017-10-17 14:18:22
```

Is it possible to have Excel add in those missing times with a corresponding blank row (so then I can do interpolation on those blank spots?)

Comment: if you use PivotTable, you can probably group by seconds to get the missing dates http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot07.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am not sure how your data look like but this is what you can do if you don't want to use VBA.

Use this formula from `cell B2` and drag down:

```
=IF(B1="","",IF(N(B1),IF(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$1)-1<SECOND(MAX($A$2:$A$7)-MIN($A$2:$A$7))+1,B1+TIME(0,0,1),""),A2))
```

What this does is to determine how many seconds between max and min and then use the rows as a reference (you can change this part based on your data structure).  Try and see if this works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! It assumes your times are in column A, with a header in cell A1

```
Sub AddRows()

'Finds out what row to go up to
 Dim lRow As Long
 lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lRow + 1

'If the difference between the cell below is more than a second, then add a 
row above and skip the next i
If Cells(i + 1, 1) - Cells(i, 1) > 0.000011575 Then
   Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
   Selection.EntireRow.Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   lRow = lRow + 1
   Cells(i + 1, 1).Select
   Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + 0.000011575
   i = i + 1

Else

End If

Next i

End Sub
```